# Listar tabela tridimensional

Tags: lua, lua-table

Tenho uma tabela que pretendo imprimir todos os seus valores.

Exemplo:

```
local table_2 = {
   ["tabela1"] = "360Mhz", "demo", "teste",
   ["tabela2"] = "360Mhz", "demo", "teste"
}
for k,v in pairs(table_2) do
   print(k,v)
end
```

Como posso imprimir os 4 valores para cada linha e em cada variável?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alguns problemas:

O exemplo do código não é uma tabela tridimensional. Se for isto, o algoritmo a seguir precisar ser modificado, mas acho que já dá para entender como fazer quando há aninhamento de tabelas (no fundo nem esse exemplo pode ser tratado com algo de várias dimensões)

A declaração das tabelas internas estão faltando delimitadores.

```
local table_2 = {
   ["tabela1"] = { "360Mhz", "demo", "teste" },
   ["tabela2"] = { "360Mhz", "demo", "teste" }
}
for k, v in pairs(table_2) do
   print(k)
   for k2, v2 in pairs(v) do
      print("   ", v2)
   end
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/o7ofzD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ammwppxz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/3DTable.lua).

Obviamente pode adaptar para imprimir da forma como deseja mas o importante aí é varrer a tabela externa e pegar seus membros que são tabelas para varrer os membros novamente. Se houver necessidade de mais um nível de aninhamento, é só fazer o mesmo e incluir mais um `for` interno.